# Get Scikit-learn classification report from confusion matrix

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, evaluation, confusion-matrix

Found this question by @CarstenWE but it had been closed with no answer: [How to get classification report from the confusion matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73308803/how-to-get-classification-report-from-the-confusion-matrix)

As the question is closed, I opened this question to provide an answer.
The questions linked to the original all have answers to compute precision, recall, and f1-score. However, none seems to use the `classification_report` as the original question asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a small function to do this using a confusion matrix as input, by creating a ground-truth vector and a predicted vector, as order does not matter for these metrics:

```py
def classification_report_from_confusion_matrix(cm, **args):

    y_true = []
    y_pred = []

    for target in range(len(cm)):
        for pred in range(len(cm)):
            y_true += [gt]*cm[target][pred]
            y_pred += [pred]*cm[target][pred]

    return metrics.classification_report(y_true , y_pred, **args)
```

This solution probably does not scale well for huge datasets, but it was enough for me.

**Edit:**

Here is a solution without using lists:

```py
def classification_report_from_confusion_matrix(confusion_matrix, **args):
    y_true = np.zeros(np.sum(confusion_matrix), dtype=int)
    y_pred = np.copy(y_true)

    i = 0
    for target in range(len(confusion_matrix)):
        for pred in range(len(confusion_matrix)):
            n = confusion_matrix[target][pred]
            y_true[i:i+n] = target
            y_pred[i:i+n] = pred
            i += n

    return metrics.classification_report(y_true, y_pred, **args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn's classification report function takes these parameters :

`sklearn.metrics.classification_report(y_true, y_pred, *, labels=None, target_names=None, sample_weight=None, digits=2, output_dict=False, zero_division='warn')`

It gives a classification report with true labels et predicted labels.

If you still want to get a classification report from a confusion matrix, you might need to compute it from scratch without using Sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small function for generating a classification report from the confusion matrix and tested it with a few confusion matrices and it worked fine.

The time complexity of this function is Θ(n<sup>3</sup>) and might not be good for large data.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
def cal_act_pred(cnf: np.ndarray) -> None:
    act = []
    pre = []
    num = cnf.shape[0]
    for i in range(num):
        for j in range(num):
            for k in range(cnf[i][j]):
                act.append(i)
                pre.append(j)
    print(classification_report(act, pre, digits=4))
```